# Many to many relationship in Voyager Admin Panel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I get this error when I try to add a new item with the many to many relationship using the BREAD creator for voyager:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in
>   field list is ambiguous (SQL: select `id` from `products` inner join
>   `order_product` on `products`.`id` = `order_product`.`product_id`
>   where `order_product`.`order_id` is null) (View:
>   D:\WindowsFolders\Documents\PHP\Voyager-test\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\bread\edit-add.blade.php)

I have followed the documentation and not really sure where I am having the issue. To me it looks like my many to many setup should work in normal Laravel, but it throws that error when I try to add a new `order` item in the voyager panel. And the documentation really don't specify what the extra field in the parent table should be(where I put a comment).

Here is my `order` and `order-pivot` table;

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->text('comment')->nullable();
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->boolean('sent');
        $table->boolean('paid');
        $table->string('products'); // This thing
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is the product table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->text('description');
        $table->string('image');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is the relationship function:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'order_product');
}
```

And lastly a picture from the `Order` BREAD part:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL error message is quite clear in this case: both `products` and `order_product` tables have `id` fields. The select list of the sql statement in the question simply has `id`, therefore MySQL cannot decide which table the `id` field should be selected from.

You need to prefix the field name with the table name to make it clear:

```
select products.id from ...
```

Comment: In other words, the problem is the code for what and how the fields should be selected and joined, not the tables themselves?

Comment: That's correct. Although, technically you could remove the id field from the order_product table and make the combination of order_id - product_id fields the primary key (you are missing a unique constraint from those 2 fields anyway).

Comment: Just to try it out, how would I go about that? MySQL/eloquent is still the most foreign about programming to me. Do you mean composite keys?

Comment: Yes, composite or multi-column key what you need. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-indexes

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it by changing the relationship key from `id` to `product_id` inside the json options in Voyager Admin